# For web applications: Git/Svn checkout (working copy) for a production site, or packaged releases?

Tags: svn

For quite some time now, I've been using a SVN working copy for my final live sites.  Doing this during development has obvious advantages, but what are the **disadvantages** to doing this in production?  I can only think of a few:

1. Hidden .svn directories could be publicly accessible if you don't have your server conifigured correctly.
2. It's very easy for you to make a commit to the project repository (even if it's not ready to be deployed), and for someone else to do an update on the production server checkout.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using svn checkout, you can use svn export and the .svn files are mnot created

I used to have a website in svn and my process was the following:

- Dev on trunk
- When happy, tag, export on a new folder
- update apache to use that folder instead of the old one. (Either on prod or staging environement).

The drawback is for your various environement to work easily / out of the box, you have to either

- patch your deployment for customisation (DB server, user...)
- store all prod / preprod / dev information in your svn server (which is a bad idea).

Whatever the way you work, finally, you need to trust the person updating the actual server : whatever the process, if it's not followed, you'll end up doomed.